# I want create a condition based on whether a person said a specific part of a statment or not in Python

Tags: python, string, input

For example, the code would only run if, let's say, the word 'print' was mentioned, otherwise it would print 'Error; text undefined. Did you mean '*print*'? However, I want want to remove the word *print* as in the input would be print('*I like ducks*') and the output would be *I like ducks*. I can't think of any way other than this:

```py
code = input('')
if (str'print') in code:
   print('Code')
else:
 print('\033[31mError; code undefined. Did you mean print?\033[0m')
```

Comment: Did you mean: `if 'print' in code:`?

Answer (score 1):

```py
code = input()
if 'print' in code:
   print('Code')
else:
   print('Error; code undefined. Did you mean print?')
```

This is the code you provided but fixed. It detects if 'print' is somewhere in the input.

Answer (score 0):

if I got you right, you want your code to print "Code" as long as you give input, if that's the case then here is the code:

```
    code = input('')
       if (len(code)!=0):
               print('Code')
       else:
       print('\033[31mError; code undefined. Did you mean print?\033[0m')
```

len function will detect if there was any input, it will give 0 for empty input